# Different Output Color When Convert to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I want to convert to Excel using C#, I have problem with the color.
I use references :

```
 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

With the Code:

```
 private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range workSheet_range = null;
 workSheet_range.Interior.Color = GetColorValue(be.InteriorColor);

 private int GetColorValue(string interiorColor)
    {
        switch (interiorColor)
        {
            case "BLUE":
                return System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue.ToArgb();
            case "YELLOW":
                return System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow.ToArgb();
            default :
                return System.Drawing.Color.White.ToArgb();
        }
    }
```

My Problem is, the source code is working fine (no error). But the color output is completely wrong. Example, when I set the interior color to *Yellow* then the output is likely *Light Chocolate*.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF00");**

Here #FFFF00 is Hexadecimal color code for Yellow.